# android scrolling not set to previous position

Tags: java, android

I have a `listview` with 400 items, however, when I'm on item 100 etc, I press `down` it would go down and all that neat stuff, but the `viewing` goes back to the top while keeping my `item 100` selected... Here is what it's doing: http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2788305924.gif

How do I prevent his? Here is what I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    try{
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Menu", "Full screen not supported under API 19 (4.4 KitKat)");
    }

    mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setDivider(null);
    listView.setFocusable(false);
    listView.setDividerHeight(0);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Channel channel = channels.get(position);
            if (position == menuAdapter.getSelectedPosition()) {
                if ((new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())).nextBoolean()) {
                    openChannel(channel);
                } else {
                    tempChannel = channel;
                    Log.i("Menu", "Playing ad");
                    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded())
                        interstitialAd.show();
                }
            } else {
                menuAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position, listView);
            }

            Picasso.with(mainActivity).load(channel.artUrl).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    BitmapDrawable bmDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    if (bmDrawable != null)
                        bmDrawable.setAlpha(80);
                    mainLinearLayout.setBackground(bmDrawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    mainActivity = this;

    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(getAdmobBannerId());
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    bannerAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getAdmobIntersitialId());
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            openChannel(tempChannel);
        }
    });
    interstitialAd.loadAd((new AdRequest.Builder()).build());

    mainLinearLayout.addView(bannerAd, 0);

    new WebServiceJob().execute();
}

public String getAdmobBannerId() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("YTApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String result = preferences.getString("admob_banner", null);
    if (result == null) {
        String defaultID = "ca-app-pub-";
        preferences.edit().putString("admob_banner", defaultID).apply();
        return defaultID;
    }
    return result;
}

public String getAdmobIntersitialId() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("YTApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String result = preferences.getString("admob_intersitial", null);
    if (result == null) {
        String defaultID = "ca-app-pub4";
        preferences.edit().putString("admob_intersitial", defaultID).apply();
        return defaultID;
    }
    return result;
}

public void artDownloaded(){
    numArtDownloaded++;
    if(numArtDownloaded == channels.size())
        updateUIWithScroll();
}

public void updateUIWithScroll(){
    updateUI();
    if(!menuAdapter.isScrolling) {
        menuAdapter.isScrolling = true;
        listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Menu", "Scrolling");
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(menuAdapter.getSelectedPosition());
                menuAdapter.isScrolling = false;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void updateUI() {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> channelNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Channel channel : channels)
            channelNames.add(channel.title);
        menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, R.layout.listitemright, channelNames, getSharedPreferences("YTApp", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("selectedChannelNr", -1));
        listView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
        if (menuAdapter.getSelectedPosition() != -1) {
            Picasso.with(mainActivity).load(channels.get(menuAdapter.getSelectedPosition()).artUrl).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    BitmapDrawable bmDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    if (bmDrawable != null)
                        bmDrawable.setAlpha(80);
                    mainLinearLayout.setBackground(bmDrawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: Is down a button inside your app?

Comment: yes, I press up and down, then it highlights my option and color it red nicely :) but the scoll goes back up when i go back to the list...

Comment: and what is viewing? a button too? do you men you want to scroll the view with your button but when you are touching it, it will scroll back to top?

Comment: it appears that my scrolled position is not saved.... please help

Comment: Here is what it's doing: http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2788305924.gif